# Posting text field content to Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase

I'm a newbie trying to connect my app to a backend (Firebase Database). Specifically, I have four fields where users enter content and I am trying to set a child node equal to each of those fields. Unfortunately, while I get no errors, nothings posts in the database. I'm not sure if I'm missing something big or small so any guidance would be really appreciated. Code is below:

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {


var ref:FIRDatabaseReference!

@IBOutlet weak var bookTitle: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var bookDescription: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var authorBiography: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var bookPurchaseLink: UITextView!


@IBAction func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let bookTitleContent = String(describing: bookTitle.text)

    let bookDescriptionContent = String(describing: bookDescription.text)

    let authorBiographyContent = String(describing: authorBiography.text)

    let bookPurchaseLinkContent = String(describing: bookPurchaseLink.text)

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    //post to database

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    self.ref.child(uuid).child("Book Info").child("Book Title").setValue(bookTitleContent)

    self.ref.child(uuid).child("Book Info").child("Book Description").setValue(bookDescriptionContent)

    self.ref.child(uuid).child("Book Info").child("Author Biography").setValue(authorBiographyContent)

    self.ref.child(uuid).child("Book Info").child("Book Purchase Link").setValue(bookPurchaseLinkContent)


    }


}
```

Comment: Wait why is the viewDidLoad function inside of the IBAction function?

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part. That fixed it. How do I give you credit for that answer?

Comment: It's all good. Nothing really. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Check Firebase Rules to Read And write.!

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}

    mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mdatabaseReference = mdatabase.getReference();
 mdatabaseReference.child("Child").setValue(Data);
```

//

Kindly have a look at  [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)

hope this may help you.!

Comment: Thanks, but I have the rules set to public, so I don't believe that is the issue.